# Chrome downloads .aspx file rather than viewing it

Tags: asp.net, file, coda, mojoportal

I'm trying to install mojoportal on my server (externally hosted) but when I go to the .aspx page the browser just downloads it where it should be loading it properly like a web page.

Whats wrong?

The file it's trying to load is:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" EnableSessionState="False" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="mojoPortal.Web.UI.Pages.SetupHome" %>
```

- I dont even know what that bit does, but that is all there is in the file i'm meant to load.

Comment: How does it behave with other browsers?

Comment: Does your server support ASP.NET hosting?

Comment: Yes, my server support hosting and its the same in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

Comment: @googleyberry My question is specific to ASP.NET hosting. Looks like the Asp.net worker process is not serving / configured to serve your aspx files. This is most likely because the IIS webserver was not configured properly.

Answer (score 1):

If its download it and not show it, means that the asp.net is NOT running on this site, and the web server see this aspx just like any file for download.